# OL3 vector/wfs one feature instead of many

Tags: openlayers-3

I have vector/wfs layers in ol3 with 1000~100000 of features. But usually this features are grouped in sets of features that are very close to each other. For performance reasons I would like to replace collection of features that are close by single feature when view is zoomed out. This single feature should be generated dynamically, and could have for example label with number of features that are replaced.

Could something like this be done with ol3?

**EDIT**:
This is good example: https://www.mbank.pl/placowki-bankomaty/, it is atm locator. When you are zoomed out it shows few features with information about number of atms in proximity.

Answer (score 0):

This is called clustering. You have a couple of options to do that.
The easiest is to use the built-in cluster source ol4 provides. api doc here--> [ol.source.Cluster](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html)

And here the official examples -->

[example1](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html?q=cluster)

[example2](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html?q=cluster)

Now if you want something more impressive consider the following [extension](https://github.com/Viglino/OL3-AnimatedCluster) (which is not part of the official ol4)

here is a [demo](http://viglino.github.io/OL3-AnimatedCluster/)

Comment: It looks good, I need more time to check it precisely, then I will accept your answer.